# Difference between width: 50% and flex: 50% in a CSS flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

When its container has a display for flex, what is the difference between setting an element to be flex: 50% and width: 50%. The outcome appears to be the same:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.table a {
  flex: 50%;
  background: grey;
}

.table2 a {
  width: 50%;
  background: grey;
}

<ul class="table">
  <a href="#">ad ds fdsaf dsfa dsfj dsf dsfj lkdsjflkdsa jflkdsja lkfjdslkjfldska jlkfdsajlkdjslkajflkd sjalkfjdslkjdsalkjdlakjfldksjflkdsjflkdsjd fdsd</a>
  <a href="#">b</a>
  <a href="#">c</a>
  <a href="#">d</a>
</ul>

<ul class="table2">
  <a href="#">ad ds fdsaf dsfa dsfj dsf dsfj lkdsjflkdsa jflkdsja lkfjdslkjfldska jlkfdsajlkdjslkajflkd sjalkfjdslkjdsalkjdlakjfldksjflkdsjflkdsjd fdsd</a>
  <a href="#">b</a>
  <a href="#">c</a>
  <a href="#">d</a>
</ul>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KAbof

Comment: Adding `<a>` elements inside `<ul>` element without having `<li>` is not a good practice.

Comment: It's not just bad practice...it's invalid HTML.

Comment: This isnt my actual code, I just want to know the answer to my question about felx

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is no effective difference in this instance.

In fact, it's because `flex` is shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` combined.

`flex-basis` defines the default size of an element before the remaining space is distributed.

So in this case, you have defined all `a` children` to 50%.

**Reference Article: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/**